# Why is my loop function in python returning a wrong value?

Tags: python, for-loop

I am learning python and my task is as such:

1. Define the function named as is_substring
2. Make it accept two arguments
3. Write the program that checks if the first parameter that has been accepted is a substring of the second parameter
4. Make it loop over the index positions in the string
5. At each position check if the current slice is equal to the target substring, return true or false accordingly

Here is my code:

```
def is_substring(target, string):
    for x in range(len(string)):
        return x==target

print(is_substring('bad', 'abracadabra'))

print(is_substring('dab', 'abracadabra'))
```

For the first call it is working fine but for the second call it saying false instead of true. Can someone tell me why is that so?

Comment: You're returning immediately on the first iteration of the loop. You're also not checking the slice, you're checking the index.

Comment: This should say `False` all the time. `x` is a number, `target` is a string, they'll never be equal.

Comment: I recommend reading https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Comment: Read step 5 of the instructions carefully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for:

```
def is_substring(target, string):
    for i, j in enumerate(string):  # i represents the index
        if target == string[i:i+len(target)]:  # used string slicing for a range that is equal to the length of the target substring
            return True
    else:
        return False


print(is_substring("dog", "dogie"))
print(is_substring("hello", "hi"))
```

Output:

```
True
False
```

Obviously this is not the easiest way to do it, but this is how you can do it to fulfill your given requirements :)

Answer (score 1):

`x` here is the index itself, as in, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, ....

A single character at an index can be fetched using `string[x]`.

However a slice uses the notation `[start:stop:step]` where the step is optional.

Here you need a slice of the length of the substring you are checking. A slice at index `x` with length `len(target)` is `string[x: len(target) + x]`

Comment: Did you read the rest of the answer? I explained how to obtain a slice. I added that `string[x]` to show the difference (explaining and getting to the answer progressively).

Comment: I apologize, I re-read the sentence and I realized the problem, I tried rewording it, if it's not good, please edit it as English is not my native language.

Answer (score -1):

`x` is always going to return `false`. Because you use `range(len())`, `x` is always an integer. `x == any_string` is always going to return `false`. Also, as the other guy said, this is a whacky way to accomplish this; but we all go through whacky things like this when we're learning.